# How to make last uploaded images appear first in foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have this code that shows uploaded images:

```
<?php    
$dir = "img/*.jpg";
$images = glob( $dir );

foreach( $images as $image ):
    echo "<img src='" . $image . "' />";
endforeach;
?>
```

but I need my last uploaded image to appear first in line. I know it's right there in front of me, but I can't see it. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [reversing the array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)  before your `foreach`.

```
<?php    
$dir = "img/*.jpg";
$images = glob( $dir );
$images = array_reverse($images);
foreach( $images as $image ):

echo "<img src='" . $image . "' />";    

endforeach;

?>
```

Comment: Worked liked a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Be sure to accept whichever answer you think is best!

Comment: this wont work if the file order is changed via gui, or if the directory is sorted my name, tho would it?

Comment: Will do. Apparently there is a timer going on. First time posting here.

Answer (score 2):

A safer bet would be to use the `filemtime()` function to get the modification time of each file and sorting according to that. See this code:

```
<?php    
$dir = "img/*.jpg";
$images = glob( $dir );

//Add this portion
foreach( $images as $image ) {
    $imagesModTimeArray[filemtime($image)] = $image;
}
krsort($imagesModTimeArray);
$images=array_values(imagesModTimeArray);
//New Portion End
foreach( $images as $image ):

echo "<img src='" . $image . "' />";    

endforeach;

?>
```

Comment: filemsort()? Is that your function? Cause it does not exist.

Comment: I tried your way, but non of the images are shown now.

Comment: fixed a typo, my bad